# Product of symmetric positive definite matrix and matrix with negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  be symmetric positive definite.  Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ have negative eigenvalues (but not necessarily symmetric).  Is it true that $AB$ has negative eigenvalues?

I'm having trouble generalizing [this excellent thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147074/product-of-positve-definite-matrix-and-seminegative-definite-matrix) to my situation since my $B$ isn't symmetric.

Comment: do you mean that $B$ is not symmetric?

Comment: haha, good catch.  typo fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. For example, take
$$A=\pmatrix{ 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}, B=\pmatrix{ 2 & -3 \\ 3 & -4}$$
Then $A$ is symmetric positive definite, $B$ has negative eigenvalues (-1, and -1), but $AB=\pmatrix{8 & -12 \\ 3 & -4}$ has only positive eigenvalues (2, and 2).

Comment: Your example $B$ has complex eigenvalues of $3\pm j2\sqrt{2}$, so it is not a counterexample for my problem.  I'm interested in the case where $B$ has negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Also, for your (non)counter example, $AB=\pmatrix{8 & -12 \\ 3 & 4}$ which has eigenvalues $6\pm \sqrt{-32}$.  I'm not sure I follow how you are computing eigenvalues...?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo: in B the 4 was supposed to be -4. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Ohhh, I see.  You have a slight typo in your definition B.