# Prove innner product of two matrix $\left<M,N\right> \le 0$ when one is seminegative definite and one is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M,N \in M_n(\Bbb{R})$, if both of them are symmetric and one is positive definite one is seminegative definite, then $\left<M,N\right> = \sum_{i,j}M_{ij}N_{i,j}\le 0$.

I can prove it using the simultaneous diagonalization process, there is alternative approach given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147083/360262). Is there more elegant proof for this question?

The second question is if we change a little bit assume that $M$ is semipositive definite and $N$ is also seminegative definite, does this result still hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is symmetric positive definite, then it can be written as $M=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_iu_i^T$ where the $\lambda_i$'s are the positive eigenvalues of $M$ and the $u_i$'s are the associated eigenvectors.

Then, we have that
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle M,N\rangle&:=&\mathrm{trace}(MN)\\
%
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{trace}(\lambda_i u_iu_i^TN)\\
%
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_i^TNu_i.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Since, $N$ is negative semidefinite, then $u_i^TNu_i\le0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ and the result follows.

If $M$ is positive semidefinite, then some of the $\lambda_i$'s are zero and, therefore, the result does not change.